# How does transact sql know which table I'm referencing in this subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a question about documentation on how t-sql decides which "column" is in scope for subqueries. I tried google-ing which turned up [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) but it didn't explain it.

Here's a runnable example. The `update` statement sets the only entry in `#a.a` to `null`. Presumably this is because the subquery reference to alias `a` resolves to table `#b` which has no rows that match value `1`, thus returning `null` to the outer `update` query.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#a') is not null
drop table #a

if object_id('tempdb..#b') is not null
drop table #b

create table #a (a int)
create table #b (a int)

insert into #a values (1)
insert into #b values (2)

update a
set a = (select a from #b as a where a.a = 1)
from #a as a
```

Is there documentation that indicates this design choice? It is otherwise ambiguous, because if I change the update statement to use a different alias, the final value in `#a.a` is `2`:

```
update aa
set a = (select a from #b as a where aa.a = 1)
from #a as aa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178050%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) reference might do a better job of explaining it.

The idea is quite simple.  A table alias is interpreted as the "first" table definition, starting with the current level of the subquery and then moving outward.  A table alias in a subquery cannot be used in an outer query, so references can only move "inward".

In your example:

```
update a
set a = (select a from #b as a where a.a = 1)
from #a as a
```

The `a.a` is referring to column `a` of table `a`.  In the subquery itself, table `a` is defined as `#b`.  That is the reference.

In this query:

```
update aa
set a = (select a from #b as a where aa.a = 1)
from #a as aa;
```

The table aliases is `aa`.  This is not defined in the subquery.  It is defined at the next level out, so it refers to `#a`.

In general, don't give different tables the same alias in a query (with the exception of aliases on subqueries that are essentially just a filtered/selected version of a specific table).  That can just lead to confusion.

Comment: Thank you for finding suitable documentation!

Answer (score 1):

In your first example there is no relationship between the outer and inner query, and so you are setting the value of column 'a' to the results of the inner query for every row in table #a. The inner query returns null, as there are no rows in #b which have the value of 1, so the column a in #a is set to null

In your second example, you are still not providing a relationship between the inner and outer query. All the inner query is doing is selecting every value from #b, because for every row in #b, the value of #a.a is 1. You might just as well have (select a from #b) as your inner query.

The reason rhat #a.a gets set to 2 is that there is only 1 row in the #b table, and its value is 2. If there were multiple rows in #b, then I think that #a.a would get set to the value of the last returned row in table #b. So if there were 2 rows in #b and the first had value 2 and the second had value 3, then I would expect that #a would be set to 3. (Or it would not execute).

Either way these are not very good pieces of SQL IMHO.

Comment: Good explanation. It won't be chosen as the accepted answer because it didn't answer the question about a request for documentation.